# How to customise Lucene whiteSpaceAnalyzer to index words without special characters?

Tags: indexing, filter, lucene, special-characters, analyzer

I don't want special characters when I am indexing words of a string. I understand StandardAnalyzer removes the special characters but it also does not index stopwords and single characters and I want to index stopwords and single characters.

Eg: list of hotel management organisation (hmo) site
Indexed words: list, of, hotel, management, organisation, hmo, site

Is there a filter for this? How can I build a custom Analyzer for this purpose? 
Maybe a filter that replaces non-alphanumeric characters with ""?

Answer (score 0):

`StandardAnalyzer` sounds like a good fit. Just construct it with an empty stopword set:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
```

As far as building your own analyzer, check the [Analyzer docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html). There is an example there of how building your own analyzer should look. If StandardAnalyzer is close, you might copy the createComponents from it as a starting point.

Comment: StandardAnalyzer comes close but it treats '.' and '@' differently at certain situations. I want an Analyzer that simply removes all the special characters.